# One Question Basic TCP/IP programming use bind() function

Tags: c, tcp

```
int serv_sock;
struct socckaddr_in serv_addr;
char *serv_port = "9190";

/*make server socket*/
serv_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
/*serv_addr struct init*/
memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_faimily = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(serv_port));
**bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));**
```

i don't understand that why use (struct sockaddr *) ?

why can't wrote  bind(serv_sock, &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); ?

why add (struct sockaddr *) type ? i don't understand

what's mean (struct sockaddr *) ?

So, i did one example

```
struct a {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
    int i = 10;
    struct a b;
    b.a = 10;
    b.b = 20;
    printf("%d \n", b.a); // A sentence
    printf("%d \n", (struct a*)b.a); // B sentence
```

it returned 10, 10; i don't understand why use '(struct a*)'..

i don't understand a,b sentence difference
i want I would like to know the difference between the type with and without '*'.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&serv_addr` has type `struct sockaddr_in *`.

However, the function `bind` expects that the argument has type `struct socckaddr *`. This is a generic type for many address families.

The `*` character in this context indicates a pointer.

From the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html):

> The actual structure passed for the addr argument will depend on the address family.  The sockaddr structure is defined as something like:
>
> ```
> struct sockaddr {
>     sa_family_t sa_family;
>     char        sa_data[14];
> }
> ```

While the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) describes `struct sockaddr_in` as:

> ```
> struct sockaddr_in {
>     sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
>     in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
>     struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
> };
> ```

The reason the the generic type exists is that IPv4 is not the only address family that exists.

The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) describes the IPv6 version:

> ```
> struct sockaddr_in6 {
>     sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* AF_INET6 */
>     in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port number */
>     uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
>     struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
>     uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* Scope ID (new in 2.4) */
> };
> ```

Note that the all start with a `sa_family_t` member, which describes which family is being represented. The `struct sockaddr` `sa_data` member is the "payload" of the struct.

Directly passing a `struct sockaddr_in *` or `struct sockaddr_in6 *` when `struct sockaddr *` is expected would cause a warning/error. The `(struct sockaddr *)` explicitly converts the pointer to the type `struct sockaddr *`, which `bind` expects.

The statement

```
printf("%d \n", (struct a*)b.a);
```

is not valid. You take an integer, convert it to a pointer to a struct, then tell `printf` to interpret that argument as an integer.